# C++Builder 10.2: Editor , how to turn off auto brace } insertion

Tags: c++, ide, c++builder

I'm an old Borland customer from the 1980s
I'm using C++ Builder 10.3 Editor
It is automatically inserting braces when I press enter to scoot
lines down.  Can this auto insert be disabled ?

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Comment: I edited the question to make the image visible. For your information, posts here are in the markdown format.

Comment: I also changed the tags so they are more relevant. Tags are important here and most users will change them if they are in the wrong category.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug, if those braces aren't "correct" for your code... either in the IDE or with your keyboard lol

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck

> Auto parenthesis

, see below:

[image: Uncheck Auto parenthesis.]